# when i run exe(MFC Dialog based application) in Win 2k3 it fails to run(MSJAVA.dll Missing error)

Tags: mfc

when i run exe(MFC Dialog based application) in Win 2k3 Fails to run(MSJAVA.dll Missing error).but the same exe runs successfully in WIN xp

Edit:
As per the solution by Goz ,I have downloaded the MSJAVA.dll and tried to run the exe,but am getting the below error,

"The Side-by-Side configuration information for "f:\test\TESTCSDATACHANGEEVENTS.EXE" contains errors. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem (14001)."

Comment: "Downloading" MSJAVA.DLL isn't a viable solution to begin with. It is not a file that you have the legal right to redistribute. Instead, find out what features of MSJAVA you are using and replace them, either with your own code or with appropriate calls to Sun's Java VM engine if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

MSJava.dll is no longer distributed with windows after a dispute between Microsoft and Sun.  If the application you are using requires it then there are plenty of places you can find it online ...

It may work if you download the Sun Java VM though ... If not you need to modify the app to remove the dependency ...

Edit:  TBH you need to really just remove that dependency on MSJava it would certainly solve the problem.  Did you try the Sun VM?  Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Use Dependency Walker to see dependency tree of your application. Probably, msjava.dll depends on some other DLLs.